# Using interrupts for two MCP23017

Tags: arduino-uno

I am creating a simple shield with two i2c `MCP23017` chips. Each `MCP23017` has two interrupt pins, but the Arduino Uno only has two interrupt pins (`pin 2` and `pin 3`).

The way I understand it, interrupts are there to tell the Arduino something has changed, so it can then poll the `MCP23017` for the latest pin reads.

How can I connect the 4 interrupt pins to my Arduinos 2 pins?

Comment: Read the datasheet for the MCP23017. It tells you how to turn the two interrupt pins into one.

Comment: I see `There are two interrupt pins, INTA and INTB, that can be associated with their respective ports, or can be logically OR’ed together so that both pins will activate if either port causes an interrupt.` but I'm new to electronics so I'm not sure what this means. Do I need to connect a chip to the two pins then connect the output to one of the interrupt pins?

Comment: No, you need to keep reading, down to where it tells you what all the registers do.

Comment: *The MIRROR bit controls how the INTA and INTB pins
function with respect to each other.
• When MIRROR = 1, the INTn pins are functionally 
OR’ed so that an interrupt on either port will cause 
both pins to activate.
• When MIRROR = 0, the INT pins are separated. 
Interrupt conditions on a port will cause its 
respective INT pin to activate.*

Comment: This MIRROR bit is set by software?

Comment: Yes. You can also set the ODR bit to make it open drain, then you can wire both chips into one int pin with a pull-up, should you wish.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - for my purposes I have two chips and two interrupt pins so enabling mirroring would work well. If you would care to move your comment to an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MCP23017 (and it's sister the SPI-based MCP23S17) can have their interrupt pins set to "mirror" mode. In this mode both pins are internally joined so when an interrupt occurs on any port both pins activate.  This is done using the `MIRROR` bit of the `IOCON` register.  Using this will turn your 4 interrupt pins into just 2, one for each Arduino INT pin.

Should you want to add more in the future, or if you find you want to use one of the interrupt pins on the Arduino for something else, there is also the `ODR` bit in the `IOCON` register. This sets the interrupt pins to be *open drain*, which means that all of them can be wired together into just one INT pin on the Arduino. Add a pullup (or enable the internal pullup) and you have have many IO expanders on one INT pin. Of course, that then means that you have to poll all the expanders to find which of them triggered the interrupt, so could slow things down somewhat depending on how you are using it.